# Numba complains about typing - but all types are being provided

Tags: python, numba, typing

I have a problem with Numba typing - I read the manual, but eventually hit a brick wall.

The function in question is a part of a bigger project - though it needs to run fast - Python lists are out of the question, hence I've decided on trying Numba. Sadly, the function fails in nopython=True mode, despite the fact that - according to my understanding - all types are being provided.

The code is as follows:

```
from Numba import jit, njit, uint8, int64, typeof

@jit(uint8[:,:,:](int64))
def findWhite(cropped):
    h1 = int64(0)
    for i in cropped:
        for j in i:
            if np.sum(j) == 765:
                h1 = h1 + int64(1)
            else:
                pass
    return h1
```

also, separately:

```
print(typeof(cropped))
array(uint8, 3d, C)
print(typeof(h1))
int64
```

In this case 'cropped' is a large uint8 3D C matrix (RGB tiff file comprehension - PIL.Image). Could someone please explain to a Numba newbie what am I doing wrong?

Comment: _the function fails_ Does it throw an error? _The function in question is a part of a bigger project - though it needs to run fast - Python lists are out of the question, hence I've decided on trying Numba._ What are you using the lists for?

Comment: Always provide a complete example. This also includes some input data in relevant size (some np.random.rand is usually enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using Numpy? That's often a good intermediate between Python lists and Numba, something like:

```
h1 = (cropped.sum(axis=-1) == 765).sum()
```

or

```
h1 = (cropped == 255).all(axis=-1).sum()
```

The example code you provide is not valid Numba. Your signature is also incorrect, since the input is a 3D array and the output an integer, it should probably be:

```
@njit(int64(uint8[:,:,:]))
```

Looping over the array like you do is not valid code. A close translation of your code would be something like this:

```
@njit(int64(uint8[:,:,:]))
def findWhite(cropped):

    h1 = int64(0)    
    ys, xs, n_bands = cropped.shape

    for i in range(ys):
        for j in range(xs):
            if cropped[i, j, :].sum() == 765:
                h1 += 1

    return h1
```

But that isn't very fast and doesn't beat Numpy on my machine. With Numba it's fine to explicitly loop over every element in an array, this is already a lot faster:

```
@njit(int64(uint8[:,:,:]))
def findWhite_numba(cropped):

    h1 = int64(0)    
    ys, xs, zs = cropped.shape

    for i in range(ys):
        for j in range(xs):

            incr = 1
            for k in range(zs):

                if cropped[i, j, k] != 255:
                    incr = 0
                    break

            h1 += incr

    return h1
```

For a 5000x5000x3 array these are the result for me:

Numpy (`h1 = (cropped == 255).all(axis=-1).sum()`):

```
427 ms ± 6.37 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

findWhite:

```
612 ms ± 6.16 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

findWhite_numba:

```
31 ms ± 1.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

A benefit of the Numpy method is that it generalizes to any amount of dimensions.

Comment: Many thanks for this, your solution helped a lot. Regarding Numpy - this is an excellent library that I would normally use, but on this occasion it's just not fast enough. Hence baby steps into Numba...